# What's the limit of the uniform initializer for initialize element in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some word to define for the language C++, one of this is the limit of the uniform initializer. In the previous version of this question I was thinking find two limit of this. But no .
So in C++11, there is the uniform initializer and what's the limit of this solution for the initialization of variable, pointeur, object, etc?

Comment: You tagged your question `C++11`, but your last example is not valid C++11. It relies on deduction guides, which is a C++17 feature. As such, it doesn't really demonstrate the limitation of uniform initialization, but rather that of class template argument deduction.

Comment: Please don't separate your C++ code with that many spaces; it makes it rather difficult to read. At the very least, spaces shouldn't be used around `::` or between a template name and its `<` starting angle bracket.

Comment: It's not clear what precisely it is you're asking about. Your first statement about other containers and list initialization is just wrong (they work just fine). And your second statement isn't about list-initialization but how the template is deduced. The second piece of code is valid; it simply does something you didn't expect.

Comment: Ask simple question, I'll assume it's a code snippet you try to use list initializer but failed.

Comment: I changed the tags since this is clearly a C++17 question.

Answer (score 1):

For uniform initialization to work as you expect, you must specify the template arguments of the vector:

```
std::vector<int> u{std::istream_iterator<int>(fs), std::istream_iterator<int>()};
```

That way, instead of the compiler trying to guess what the vector is supposed to contain, you specify int. This is great because now the compiler has no choice but to pick the iterator constructor instead of a vector of iterator.